# How to reply to an email to add a comment on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

## Background

Facebook sends me emails about new comments with the following footer:

[image: email footer]

## Problem

If I reply to this email from my email associated with my Facebook account, I receive the following error:

[image: email error]

## Question

How can I reply to a comment on Facebook by email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has removed email functionality back in mid of 2014.

Might be they have forget to remove this *Reply to this email to add a comment.* from email notification. You can **Report a Problem** to Facebook or report it to the Notification team:  https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=236395803106201.